# Can I determine if I can use postMessage with a targetOrigin without try/catch?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, identityserver4, openid-connect, postmessage

I'm implementing the [OIDC's Session](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) feature, which requires the use of `window.postMessage` to exchange messages between `<iframe>` elements from different Origins.

My OIDC IdP is IdentityServer4. As far as this QA is concerned I have no control over the `/connect/checksession` page.

My top-level page's HTML looks like this:

```html
<body>

    <!-- etc -->

    <iframe id="localCheckSessionIFrame" src="/local-check-session" loading="eager"></iframe>
    <iframe id="idpCheckSessionIFrame" src="https://example.com/connect/checksession" loading="eager"></iframe>

</body>
```

The document at `/local-check-session` has a `<script>` that does this:

```js
var myClientId     = 'MyClientId';
var mySessionState = 'sQZ7Tyv9NYuMVwiydWMZetcetcetc...';

window.addEventListener( "message", onReceiveMessage, /*useCapture:*/ false );
// `function onReceiveMessage` omited for brevity.

checkSession();

var timerId = window.setInterval( checkSession, 5000 );

function checkSession() {

    const idpIFrame = window.top.document.getElementById( 'idpCheckSessionIFrame' );
    if( !idpIFrame ) return;
    idpIFrame.contentWindow.postMessage( /*message:*/ `${myClientId} ${mySessionState}`, /*targetOrigin: */ "https://example.com" );
}
```

---

- The problem is that `idpIFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(...)` will fail (by throwing a `DOMException`) when the `targetOrigin` parameter doesn't match the `<iframe>`'s actual Origin.
- ...and this happens *right when* the top-level page loads for the first time:

  - `<iframe id="localCheckSessionIFrame">` will be loaded and runs the `function checkSession()` immediately.
  - ...but the `<iframe id="idpCheckSessionIFrame">` will still be loading (which can take take 2-5 seconds) - before its loaded the `idpCheckSessionIFrame`s Origin will be the same as `localCheckSessionIFrame`.

---

My initial workaround attempt was to test if `if( idpIFrame.contentWindow.origin !== "https://example.com" ) { /*OK*/ }`, however this *doesn't work at all* because cross-origin scripts will throw an error if they attempt to dereference the `contentWindow.origin` property.

```js
// This doesn't work: dereferencing `contentWindow.origin` throws an error when idpIFrame is cross-origin.
if( idpIFrame.contentWindow.origin === "https://example.com" ) {
    idpIFrame.contentWindow.postMessage( message, /*targetOrigin: */ "https://example.com" );
}
```

My second attempt was to add an inline `onload=""` listener to set a flag, i.e.: `<iframe id="idpCheckSessionIFrame" onload="this.dataset['loaded'] = '1'">` - however as far as I can tell the `onload=""` listener won't be invoked *at all* for cross-origin iframes.

My third, and current, workaround so-far is to wrap the `idpIFrame.contentWindow.postMessage` call in a `try/catch` and to ignore the exception if no successful `postMessage` had completed yet, like so:

```js
var countPostMessageOK = 0;

function checkSession() {

    const idpIFrame = window.top.document.getElementById( 'idpCheckSessionIFrame' );
    if( !idpIFrame ) return;

    try {
        idpIFrame.contentWindow.postMessage( /*message:*/ `${myclientid} ${mysessionstate}`, /*targetOrigin: */ "https://example.com" );
        countPostMessageOK += 1;
    }
    catch( err ) {
        if( countPostMessageOK === 0 && ( err instanceof DOMException ) ) {
            // Ignore.
        }
        else {
            console.error( "postMessage failed: %o", err );
        }
    }
}
```

But this isn't ideal because an exception is still being thrown, and I'm wary of possibly encountering *other* `DOMException` errors which should be re-thrown or reported instead of ignored.

Another possible workaround is to customize the IdP's `/connect/checksession` page such that other pages can use `targetOrigin: *` to first establish that the `/connect/checksession` page is finally loaded (and to initially ignore any response messages as `targetOrigin: *` means we can't trust the `<iframe>` yet), then switch to specifying the actual `targetOrigin` and trusting the results after the first response message is received - however, for now, I cannot customize the `/connect/checksession` `<script>` - but if this is the only option I guess I'll have to go with that (eventually).

---

Is there any way to test/check if `idpIFrame.contentWindow`'s Origin matches the `postMessage` `targetOrigin` *before* calling `postMessage` *without* needing any `try/catch` blocks?